# Any way to set a timer/limit for a slow URL reference?

Tags: javascript, url, timer, timeout

On my site, I have a facebook 'like' button...but once in awhile facebook is unresponsive (or very slow), and it causes other subsequent parts of my page to be blank, waiting for facebook to finally respond.

I have the same problem with some of the members of my site, who link photos from their online photo albums -- if the host site is slow or not responding, it stalls the entire page.

Is there a way to set a timer on external links -- say for example if no response within 2000ms, then just skip the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a timeout of 2000 ms at the end of the page. In the callback function, you would then loop through all the linked resources (either by querying the document with `getElementsBy*` or simply going through `document.images`) and check their state. If the resource was not loaded, you would replace it with something like `Resource not available` or do whatever you need.

For the readiness check of `HTMLImageElement`, there is its `complete` boolean property (HTML5) or in IE, its `readyState` numeric property.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
  var resources = document.images;
  var resource, message;
  for (var i = 0, ii = resources.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    resource = resources[i];
    if (typeof resource.complete !== 'undefined' && !resource.complete) {
      message = document.createTextNode('Resource not available');
      resource.parentNode.insertBefore(message, resource);
      resource.parentNode.removeChild(resource);
    }
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: thank you...I tried to vote this 'up' but apparently my reputation at this site is bad...but thanks, anyway.

Comment: You should just accept the answer using the tick below the answer score then.